# How to define functions from declarations where the parameters do not have identifiers?

Tags: c, parameters, declaration, identifier, function-declaration

For an assignment, I was given a header file. The objective was to write the function definitions in a C file.

I am confused about how to write the definition for the functions when some of them do not have identifier names.

```
#include <stdint.h>

/** Course subjects. */
enum subject {

    SUBJ_ENGI,
    SUBJ_CIV,
    SUBJ_ECE,
    SUBJ_MECH,
    SUBJ_ONAE,
    SUBJ_PROC,
    SUBJ_CHEM,
    SUBJ_ENGL,
    SUBJ_MATH,
    SUBJ_PHYS,
};

struct course;

// Define the following functions:

struct course*  course_create(enum subject, uint16_t code);

enum subject    course_subject(const struct course*);

uint16_t    course_code(const struct course*);

void        course_hold(struct course*);

void        course_release(struct course*);

int     course_refcount(const struct course*);
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to define these functions when the prototypes do not have identifier names. For example, wouldn't it make more sense for the parameter to be `const struct course* <Identifier>` instead of just `const struct course*`?

Comment: The identifier is not part of the "function signature". It can also be different in different declarations, including the one with the definition. It does not have to be there; it can even be absent in the definition if it is never used in the body (e.g. `int f(char *) { return 3; }`). When you write the definitions simply invent pretty names for the parameters which tell the reader what they mean.

Comment: By the way, you'll also need to have the full definition of `struct course`. In this header, `struct course`  is an "incomplete type"; We know nothing but that it exists, with that name. It is possible to use *pointers* to incomplete types because pointers are all alike; the compiler can produce code for pointer passing, pointer assignment etc. without knowing how big the struct itself is, or what's in it. As soon as you want to use the struct's contents though (through a pointer with -> or an object with `.`), you'll need the full struct definition.

Comment: By the way, keeping the definition of the struct hidden is good software engineering, for at least two reasons (no need to recompile so much when the struct changes, secrecy and isolation).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Re “pointers are all alike”: The C standard does not require pointers to be all alike. Pointers to `void` and character types must have the same representation as each other. Pointers to all structure types must have the same representation as each other. Pointers to union types must have the same representation as each other. Pointers to the same or differently qualified versions of a compatible type must have the same representation as each other. Other than that, pointers to different types may have different representations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the clarification; so *all pointers to structs* are alike.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: You say that you can use `int f(char *) { return 3; }` — that is not valid in standard C17 or any earlier version of the C standard.  It is, and always has been, valid in C++, and it will become valid in C23.  It is probable that GCC (and Clang emulating GCC) already allow it, but using `-Wall -Wextra -Werro -pedantic -pedantic-errors` should trigger an error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wow. I would just have lost $100. So nothing I said was true, how deplorable.

Comment: You should be able to download [N3054](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf) which is a working draft of the C23 standard from 2022-09-03.  I'm not sure whether any later drafts will be publicly available.  AFAIK, ISO closes public access to standards at the CD (committee draft) stage, and expects you to buy the standard once it is published.   See §6.9.1 Function definitions on p160 and footnote 205 for 'parameter names are optional in function definitions'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations are not definitions, the following code in the header file are declarations:

```
struct course;
enum subject    course_subject(const struct course*);
```

You don't need to have parameter name in declarations, you need them in definitions. e.g. in implementation .c file, you could have:

```
struct course {
    // add your fields
};

enum subject  course_subject(const struct course* c)
{
    // access c's fields
}
```

in this case you will have to provide a name for the `course` parameter so that you can refer to it.

Comment: .. and if you are not using it, you don't even need a name there either (which sometimes happens in real life).

Comment: Re “You don't need to have parameter name in declarations, not even in definitions”: Function definitions are specified in C 2018 6.9.1. Paragraph 2, which is a constraints paragraph, says “If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the declaration of each parameter shall include an identifier, except for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single parameter of type void, in which case there shall not be an identifier…” So, in strictly conforming C, parameters in a parameter type list must include an identifier…

Comment: … In code that is conforming but not strictly conforming, a compiler could accept a parameter declaration without a name, but it would be required to emit a diagnostic message. In the alternative case, where the function declaration uses an identifier list rather than a parameter type list, then all the parameters necessarily have identifiers, as that is what an identifier list does.

Comment: Right it's true, it's always better to write standard conforming code.

Comment: Note that parameters without names in function definitions have always been allowed in C++, and will be allowed in C23.

Comment: Just found out it is proposed in N2510 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2510.pdf. Good to know it's happening in C23.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter names are not needed in declarations because C matches arguments to parameters by position, not by name. Parameter names are needed inside a function definition so the body of the function has a way to refer to the function.

Define the functions using any parameter names you want. Simply repeat the declaration, insert whatever you want for the missing names, and replace the `;` that terminates the declaration by a `{…}` compound statement that defines the function.